# Optimization tab is missing from Sitecore Experience Editor Ribbon

Tags: experience-editor, experience-optimization

I see that this Optimization tab (in screenshot) is missing  from my Sitecore Experience Editor Ribbon.

I checked and Xdb is enabled and working fine.

Can somebody suggest what can be the reason for this apart from Xdb?

[image]

Comment: Which sitecore version is in use?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are logging with regular user which doesn't have "admin rights".
In this case, your user needs to inherit from `sitecore\Author` or one of these roles `sitecore\Analytics Personalization` and `sitecore\Analytics Testing`.

Also make sure your user is not inheriting this role `sitecore\Sitecore Limited Page Editor` - This is speeding up loading times of **Experience Editor (EE)** significantly but also limits / degrades the functionality of **EE** significantly

Comment: The screenshot shows the user logged in is "Administrator" however.

Comment: @MarkCassidy you are right. Its admin user.I think I got the issue. Compared core database with Vanilla instance and there is difference between the two. We have upgraded from old instance to Sitecore 9.2 and I think this feature was not available in old instances. So thats why its missing. I'll raise a ticket to Sitecore regarding this.

Comment: Yes Mark but also @aruntiwari wrote he is missing it so I thought this is the difference that with admin all is good and the tab is there but with this user, tab is missing...

Comment: @aruntiwari - What was the outcome of the Sitecore ticket? Is there a specific package for Optimization tab or a general package for Content Testing feature?

Comment: The Optimization item in core db was moved to some other location to hide it from EE by some developer to improve performance of Experience Editor. I moved it bacj and it worked fine.

Comment: It was actually not general Sitecore issue due to customization by us.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have this item in Core database "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Optimization". WebEdit children items are  what is shown in Experience Editor ribbon. Also make sure you have all necessary ContentTesting configuration files enabled so that Optimization features will work properly. They are located in ContentTesting folder in App_Config\Include or in App_Config\Sitecore depending which version you are using.